# What technologies should I use as a web freelancer?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development

I would like to be a web freelancer but I'm in doubt because I'm not sure if the services I'm going to offer are even relevant in 2022. I know a lot about building websites using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Django.

I would like to start building landing pages using HTML and CSS but it seems to me that nobody really needs this because there are platforms like Wordpress, Wix, Tilda etc. Websites built using these platforms are easy to handle and edit by users with little to no technical knowledge because of CMS they offer, which of course I'm not able to provide.

So, my question is, does somebody really need a page built with basic technologies like HTML, CSS and JS, or I should abandon this idea, learn something like Wordpress, and offer to build websites using this platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are not the people to answer this question. The only people who can answer this are your potential customers.

How to get an answer to this question? The best way is to put together some marketing materials (pamphlet, hand out, etc.) that describes the type of business problem you are offering to solve which is building a static web site. Then, go out and talk to potential customers and see how they react. Do they say I like what you offer, but don't want to pay your price. Or do they say that they need something else solved. If they do, then learn how to solve that something else. Repeat. Do this enough till you find a customer who will pay you to solve that problem.